# Setting variables through href

Tags: php, html, href

So, this link needs to set busqueda = null, orden = 3 and categoria = ''
I can get it to store one of these but I dont know how to keep the other ones.

```
<a href="buscar.php?busqueda=null">Catalogo</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&` sign to accept more than one get parameters.

Snippet

```
<a href="buscar.php?busqueda=null&orden=3&categoria=''">Catalogo</a>
```

Output

```
Array ( 
    [busqueda] => null
    [orden] => 3
    [categoria] => '' 
    )
```